# WPF equivalent for OnHandleCreated (from C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any equivalent for `OnHandleCreated` for a window in `WPF` similar to the one in C# for a form?

My intention is to get the handle for the window and not for it's child controls. I want to access this handle after it is created. In winforms we could use OnHandleCreated to get the handle as soon as it is created. Is it any alternative for this in WPF window?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `Handle` for Wpf controls except `Window`. It will be better if you can tell what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: WPF is not winforms. Whatever you're trying to do you should use WPF's own mechanisms as opposed to trying to force WPF to an awkward winforms approach.

Comment: Keep in mind that a WinForms control is a child window, so OnHandleCreated makes sense.  Whereas a WPF window will render all visual children on one surface, resulting in no child window objects.  So as @SriramSakthivel points out, it would be better to understand your intent.

Comment: Hi. My intention is to get the handle for the window and not for it's child controls. 
I want to access this handle after it is created. In winforms we could use OnHandleCreated to get the handle as soon as it is created. Is it any alternative for this in WPF window?

Comment: Your comment is same as your question.

Comment: I updated my question later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Window.OnSourceInitialized` method:

```
class MyWindow : Window
{
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
         var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
         // -- or --
         var hwndSource = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
         var handle = hwndSource.Handle;
    }
}
```

`HwndSource` exposes other interop mechanisms, such as adding a hook for the message loop. If you don't need that, just use `WindowInteropHelper`.